# Vim nnoremap creates `n <Esc> * <<_`

Tags: vim, neovim

Hi for some reason when I create a binding `nnoremap <c-[> <<_`
it creates additional normal mode bindind which looks like `n <Esc> * <<_` in `:nmap`, which results in shifting lines indent every time when I press Escape key in normal mode. I did not map Esc binding it sort of commes as side effect of `nnoremap <c-[> <<_` as if I comment out this line strange behaviour disappears if I source $MYVIMRC file with the commented line it does not remove the Esc binding I have to exit and open nvim in order for this to take effect. Do you know what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Control-[</kbd> **is** <kbd>Esc</kbd>. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character:

> 27 (escape, ESC, \e (GCC only), **^[**). Introduces an escape sequence.

Comment: I'll just point out that since these produce exactly the same byte sequence to the terminal, there is no way for Vim (or any other terminal program) to distinguish them.  Some people take advantage of this and use `Ctrl-[` if `Esc` is difficult to use (e.g., on a Mac).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't see `Control-[` there.

Comment: @phd pretty sure the text explains how control sets certain bits, making it the same as escape.